# Is there a way to find users that are not in any of my groups?

Tags: google-contacts

I like to organize things, and if it was up to me, all the contacts from contacts.google.com would be inside a group. most of them are, but I cannot find the ones that are not. Is there a way to filter my contacts to show this?

Comment: Unfortunately, the search function in Contacts isn't great.

Answer (score 1):

One convoluted way:

1. Add *all* of your contacts into a generic group (e.g., `Ungrouped`)
2. Visit each of contact groups in turn, select all of the contacts in that group, and remove them from the group created in step 1
3. Once done, all of your contacts not previously in a group will be in `Ungrouped`

Answer (score 1):

If you export your contacts to a CSV file, you can use that to find the contacts without a group membership.

If you export Google CSV format, the column name is "Group Membership". If you export Outlook CSV format, the column name is "Categories".

Simply open the CSV file in any spreadsheet (including Google Sheets), follow whatever steps are needed to import the data, and then look for the records with nothing in the appropriate column.